# electrostatic shielding

Tags: electrostatics, conductors

When we have an uncharged conductor with a cavity and apply an external electric field, the charges rearrange to keep the electric field inside the metal zero. The driving force is the need to keep electric field inside the metallic layer, zero. Then why is the field inside the cavity also zero? I think this is because the charges would arrange in the same way as in the case of a cavity free conductor but why can't they arrange in a different way?[image]

Why is this arrangement not possible which clearly has a field inside the cavity but not inside the metal?

Comment: The diagram is not correct as there are no induced charges on the inside surface  of the conductor.  All the induced charges reside on the outside surface of the conductor.

Comment: @Farcher Your approach is easier for me to understand but why can the inner surface not have induced charges? Your answer states that if we took a charge from inner negative surface to outer positive surface we have some +ve work which violates the condition but you didn't mention the work done by the external electric field. Those cancel out.

Comment: My answer took a charge from one place on the **inner** surface of the conducting shell to another place on the **inner** surface of the conducting shell.  An electric field inside the cavity would mean that there must be a potential gradient inside the cavity which is not the case.

Answer (score 4):

The cavity has no field inside because the metal boundary enclosing it is an equipotential. And the solution of Laplace equation for the potential inside is a constant corresponding to this potential due to the boundary condition. Therefore there is no electric field inside.

Comment: Why is the inside surface equipotential? What is the problem with the arrangement I proposed? I'm sorry but I don't know what's the Laplace equation.

Comment: Do you know Gauss' law? Within the conductor there is no electric field, that field is completely canceled by the surface charge that you induce with the external field. As there is no electric field within, there is no reason that charges would arrange in any special way. Your drawing assumes that the electric field somehow still manages to penetrate the conductor, which is exactly what *does not* happen.

Comment: @Martin Ueding doesn't the electric field need to penetrate the conductor to have any arrangement?  Also I know the gauss law.

Comment: Your picture is a bit misleading. The charges will accumulate on the surface of the conductor.

Comment: True, and the uniqueness theorem for Laplace's equation also makes this the only possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

If there is an electric field inside the conducting shell then there must be electric charges on the inner surface of the conducting shell because electric field lines start on positive charges and finish on negative charges.

Start near one of the negative charges on the inside surface of the conducting shell and walk along an electric field line carrying a positive charge until you reach a region near a positive charge on the inside surface of the conducting shell.
The region near the positive charge is at the same potential as the inside surface of the conducting shell near where the negative charge resided because the metallic shell is an equipotential volume.

But you must have done work to move the positive change along the electric field line and hence moved from a region of low potential to a region of higher potential which contradicts the statement that the conductor is an equipotential volume.

Thus there can be no electric field inside the inside surface of the conducting shell.

Comment: There's an electric field inside the cavity from the external electric source.

Comment: @JohnMcVirgo What makes you think that there is an electric field inside the cavity?

Comment: The question says a conductor with a cavity is placed in an external field, so there's an external field inside the shell which contradicts the arguments of  your first paragraph. Whether or not this gets canceled by the internal electric field generated by the conductor isn't the point I was trying to make.

Comment: @JohnMcVirgo When placed in an external electric field a conductor has charges induced on the outside of the conductor.  Those induced charges produce an electric field in opposition to the external electric field such that the resultant field everywhere inside the conductor (both inside the conductor itself and the cavity) is zero.  I tried to show you that there can be no electric field inside the cavity.  If there was there must be induced charges on the inside surface of the conductor which I showed cannot happen.

Comment: When we move from the inner negative side to outer positive side, we also have an opposing external electric field. That makes the net work 0.

Comment: @JohnMcVirgo I showed in my answer that there cannot be any induced charges on the inner side of the conductor.

Comment: "If there is an electric field inside the conducting shell then there must be electric charges on the inner surface of the conducting shell because electric field lines start on positive charges and finish on negative charges." Take free space outside the conductor with the external electric field. I can draw an identical imaginary conducting cavity. Your argument in its current form still applies here: there must be charges on the surface of this imaginary cavity because there's a field inside the imaginary cavity, which isn't true.

Answer (score 0):

There must not be any electric field within a conductor. This is why the (blue) charges will arrange against the external (red) field. Those blue charges generate an electric field on their own, the blue field. The strength of the blue field is exactly such that it cancels the red one. Until that is the case, the unmatched part of the red field will move electrons within the conductor.

Because the field cancels in the inside, there is no shifting of charges (polarization) and no surface charge in the cavity.

[image]

Comment: Yes I get the explanation for this arrangement. Now what if we have charges of opposite polarity on each of the inner sides of the sphere? How does that not satisfy any of the given conditions?

Comment: The configuration in my picture does not have a net electric field in the inside. If there was polarization in the middle, it would create an additional electric field. That field would pull on the charges and move them such that the cavity becomes neutral again. Any field in the inside would not be able penetrate the conductor because the charges would quickly rearrange themselves such that the field is canceled. If the field was from the charges themselves, the polarization would just go away.