# Electrostatic shielding : charge inside a cavity

Tags: electrostatics

Can somebody explain as to why doesn't a charge , placed outside the cavity of a conductor , produce any electric field on a charged particle placed inside the cavity.

Comment: Did you look at previous answers to the same or similar questions? Like this: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/283708/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [electrostatic shielding](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/283708/)

Comment: I encourage you to give references for your assertion and to explain why you think the questions indicated as duplicates are not adequately answered.